# Rails : Error multiple file upload, empty array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, cloudinary

i have big problem, my rails application cannot upload photos correctly i get this error every time.

you can se on right of photos cannot upload cloudinary url

[image: a busy cat]

I have to do this since the admin and not from the site itself to add pictures

cars_controller.rb

```
def index
 @cars = Car.all()
end

def show
 @car = Car.friendly.find(params[:id])
 @photos = @car.photos
 end
end
```

photos_uploader.rb

```
 include Cloudinary::CarrierWave

 def store_dir
 "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
 end

 def extension_whitelist
  %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
 end
```

photo.rb

```
mount_uploaders :photos, PhotosUploader
belongs_to :car
```

car.rb

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader

has_many :photos
```

You can see my error

[image: error]

Comment: Please don't use screenshots of errors or code. We need to be able to easily read your stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mount_uploaders` are not currently supported in the Cloudinary Ruby gem. The issue can be tracked here https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/issues/304.

There is a sample project (https://github.com/taragano/Cloudinary_multiple_uploads) that illustrates a temporary workaround. The models are album and photo, where album has a `has_many` relationship to photos and photo has a `belongs_to` relationship to album.

The models (https://github.com/taragano/Cloudinary_multiple_uploads/tree/master/app/models) should look like this:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :album
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
end
```

While in the controller (https://github.com/taragano/Cloudinary_multiple_uploads/blob/master/app/controllers/albums_controller.rb), you'll need to iterate over each photo and store it to the album that it belongs to:

```
def store_photos
    photos = params[:album][:photos]
    photos.each{|photo| @album.photos.create(image: photo)} if photos
end
```